# How can I invalidate a touches moved method in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, invalidation, touchesmoved

I have a touchesmoved method that moves a ball depending on the position of the user's touch.  How can I stop the ball from being dragged after the user gets a "Game Over".

Example - An NSTimer will be cancelled by calling [NSTimer invalidate]. How can I do that but with a touchesmoved method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could disable user interaction in the view: `view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

That way the touchesMoved function would not be called, but would also disable any UI elements in that view.

Another option is to have a `BOOL gameOver` variable, and in your touchesMoved function check the value, if it's true, return immediately and do nothing.

Comment: Using the BOOL worked perfectly! I can't believe I didn't think of it before. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, since it worked for you, don't forget to upvote and accept my answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow.